# Excel VBA Formula Dragging

Tags: excel, vba

I have data in Column A, in Column B I fill formula and drag till the data ends corresponding to Column A. But the problem is Column A is not constant, every time it changes, so how to do auto fill according to data change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fill the formula into the entire range without having to put it into B2 and then filling down.

```
Cells(2, "B").resize(cells(rows.count, "A").end(xlup).row -1, 1).formula = "=A2"
```

... or,

```
Range("B2:B" & cells(rows.count, "A").end(xlup).row).formula = "=A2"
```